# Android MediaPlayer playback default speed slow

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm learnin to use MediaPlayer，but I got a problem. When I run the app in AVD and play the audio, the audio sound very stranger, the speed is slower than the normal, and the pitch is lower as well. I also replaced my audio, but still the same. My audio file is under res\raw

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, R.raw.number_one);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

Comment: that's AVD. It also depends on the AVD settings. Have you tried on real device?

Comment: I don't have a real device with me right now, I will try it later. Thanks.

Comment: what is format of this number_one file?